# How to resolve the issue (Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'MyDataSource')?

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, angular6

Im using filters & getting the below error. Dont know where Im going wrong. Can anyone please help me in resolving this?

please find my code below:

I have tried including this also,

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';

export class ComplaintsComponent implements OnInit {
  dataSource: MyDataSource | null;

  dataSubject = new BehaviorSubject < any[] > ([]);

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['Complaint_No', 'MobileNo', 'ComplaintDate'];


  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource = new MyDataSource(this.dataSubject);
  }
 }
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Are you using MatTable?

Comment: what is MyDataSource?

Comment: @SiddAjmera yes

Answer (score 0):

You're using `MyDataSource` as the type of your `dataSource`. Not really sure what that is. But make sure that it extends [**`MatTableDataSource`**](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatTableDataSource) as that's what you'll need to have as the signature of your `MyDataSource` in order to get the `filter` property on it.